# Listen to multiple documents in a collection and update recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure how to listen changes in a Firestore db and update items in `RecyclerView`.

I am trying to do a chat application using a Firestore db. Right now I would like to implement a feature that a sender can see if a receiver has seen a message or not. Initially there is "delivered" status near the last message from sender. As soon as receiver opens a chat room the status should change to "seen". 
I am following a tutorial "Chat App with Firebase Part 14" by KOD Dev on YouTube but using Firestore db instead of Realtime database.

There are parts of Chat model, Activity with `RecyclerView` and Adapter.

```
public class Chat {
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String message;
    private boolean isseen;
    public Date sent_timestamp;

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message, boolean isseen, Date sent_timestamp) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
        this.isseen = isseen;
        this.sent_timestamp = sent_timestamp;

private void seenMessage(final String userid) {
        Query query = mFirebaseFirestore.collection("Chats");
        query.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        QueryDocumentSnapshot docEvent = doc.getDocument();
                        Chat chat = doc.getDocument().toObject(Chat.class);
                        if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid)) {
                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("isseen", true);
                            doc.getDocument().getReference().update(hashMap);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

private void readMessages(final String myid, final String userid, final String imageurl) {
        mchat = new ArrayList<>();
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mchat, imageurl);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        Query query = mFirebaseFirestore.collection("Chats").orderBy("sent_timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        query.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        QueryDocumentSnapshot docEvent = doc.getDocument();
                        Chat chat = doc.getDocument().toObject(Chat.class);
                        if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                                chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(myid)) {
                            mchat.add(chat);
                        }
                    }
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat = mChat.get(position);
        if (position == mChat.size() - 1) {
            if (chat.isIsseen()) {
                holder.txt_seen.setText("Seen");
            } else {
                holder.txt_seen.setText("Delivered");
            }
        } else {
            holder.txt_seen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

As soon as value "isseen" changes to "true" it should be displayed on the sender's phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
Query query = mFirebaseFirestore.collection("Chats").whereEqualTo("isseen", true);
```

It will give list of all messages where isseen=true, as well as when any "isseen" changes to true in real time.

Answer (score 0):

I did not follow that tutorial but I can tell you how would I implement the *seen feature* in my [chat app](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

So I'd try to keep track of the last message that a particular user has already seen. Beucase in most of the cases in a chat applications, the messages are displayed ordered by their creation timestamp, it means that you'll need to keep track the timestamp of the latest message they've seen. Because on a large scale in a multiuser environment, there can be moments in which two users can read the same message in the same, I recommend you also store its document id. Having this information, you can now query only the new documents that are new after the last stored timestamp:

```
yourCollRef.startAfter(...)...
```